# Calculate median value for a column, output the value and say if "OK" or "ERROR" if within or outside acceptable range

Tags: linux, awk

I would like to calculate the median value of a particular column in a .txt file, output that value and also say if that output value is ok. I can do the initial steps and output the median value, however it cannot say if the output value is within the acceptable range.

I get a syntax error message with the following code:

```
$ sort -nk9 filename | awk '{a[i++]=$9;} END {x=int((i+1)/2); y=((a[x-1] + a[x])/2); z=(a[x-1]); if ((y >= 0.5 && y <= 2) || (z >= 0.5 && z <=2)); {if (x < (i+1)/2) print "Median OR =", y "ALL OK"; else print "Median OR =", z "ALL OK"}; else print "ERROR - OR outside range 0.5 - 2.0"}'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors with the `if` `else` structure in `awk`
Using one line, makes it hard to read, understand.  This should be ok:

```
sort -nk9 t | awk '
    {a[i++]=$9;} 
END {
    x=int((i+1)/2)
    y=((a[x-1] + a[x])/2)
    z=(a[x-1])
    if ((y >= 0.5 && y <= 2) || (z >= 0.5 && z <=2))
        {if (x < (i+1)/2) print "Median OR =", y "ALL OK"
            else print "Median OR =", z "ALL OK"}
        else print "ERROR - OR outside range 0.5 - 2.0"}'
```